# Simple_Add DPC++ oneAPI example fails to run

Tags: c++, intel-oneapi, dpc++

I am trying to run a basic Simple_Add DPC++ example from the oneAPI sample browser; I using VS2019 and oneAPI toolkit 2021 Beta Update 10.
Running the project, it crashes here

`queue q(d_selector, dpc_common::exception_handler);`

throwing the exception below

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF6915FB99 (igdrcl64.dll) in simple-add-buffers.exe: 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero.
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFF6915FB99 (igdrcl64.dll) in simple-add-buffers.exe: 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero.
```

All project samples fail there.

Answer (score 0):

I solved installing the latest Intel driver for the graphic card with this `igfx_win10_100.9168.exe` package.